# How to create a toggle button inside a column in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to create this view. But I don't know how to make this kind of button, is it feasible with C#? If so, Please help me.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKJbH.jpg]

Comment: The question is : What do you mean by 'Column'? Each of your button has a bool but also some sort of string above it or maybe two numbers? So: Where do you want to store these data? Displaying the two on/off bitmaps is not hard but you need to decide just what control(s) to use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a ListView you can get something that looks like your image by

- splitting the data into the `Text` and the `Tags` of each `Item/Subitem`
- owner-drawing the `ListView`
- storing the two images (including headroom) in two `Bitmaps`.
- Coding the `MouseDown` event to bring the 'buttons' to live

[image]

Here is the code for owner-drawing.

```
private void listView3_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle textBounds = e.Bounds; textBounds.Height /= 2;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(e.Item.Text == "True" ? bmpOn : bmpOff, e.Bounds.Location);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Item.Tag.ToString(), 
                          Font, textBounds, Color.Black, TFFcenter);
}

private void listView3_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle textBounds = e.Bounds; textBounds.Height /= 2;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(e.SubItem.Text == "True" ? bmpOn : bmpOff, e.Bounds.Location);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.SubItem.Tag.ToString(), 
                          Font, textBounds, Color.Black, TFFcenter);
}


private void listView3_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}
```

The code to process clicking on a `ListView` is simple but not obvious:

```
private void listView3_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewHitTestInfo HI = listView3.HitTest(e.Location);
    if (HI.SubItem != null) HI.SubItem.Text = HI.SubItem.Text == "True" ? "False" : "True";
    else if (HI.Item != null) HI.Item.Text = HI.Item.Text == "True" ? "False" : "True";
}
```

The `DrawText` call uses  `TextFormatFlags` to center the text in the upper half:

```
TextFormatFlags TFFcenter = 
                TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;
```

The trick is in preparing the whole `ListView`.

For my test I used this routine:

```
ImageList il = new ImageList();
il.ImageSize = new Size(1, bmpOff.Height);
listView3.SmallImageList = il;
for (int c = 0; c < listView3.Columns.Count; c++)
         listView3.Columns[c].Width = bmpOff.Width;

for (int i = 0; i < listView3.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem( (i % 2 == 0).ToString() );
    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    {
        lvi.SubItems.Add( ( (c+i) % 2 == 0).ToString());
        lvi.SubItems[c].Tag = "3/7";
    }
    lvi.Tag = "3/7";
    listView3.Items.Add(lvi);

}
listView3.Width = listView3.Columns.Count * bmpOff.Width + 4;
```

Note how I use a dummy `ImageList` to enforce the `Item` heights..but while you're at it, it is probably a better idea to add the `ImageList` in the Designer and store the `Bitmaps` in it..

When you want to access/change the text displayed above the buttons you need to use the `Tag` of each `Item/Subitem`..!

It is also possible to use a `DataGridView` and get the same look by cell painting it.

Note that none of the solutions lends itself well to databinding as you have too many data to bind per item/cell!

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Forms. (That it looks like what you are using.) You can drop a DataGridView on a form and change the ColumnType in the GridView designer to DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn. This will give you the Functionality that you are looking for.

In other words, if you dont mind the look, (But need the same functionality) you could use a Checkbox in your grid.

When you have the correct functionality : You can use the above answer from Gnqz, to get the Look of the button.